# Why is generalised complex structure defined to be a reduction of structure group to $O(n,n) \cap Gl(n,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-structures

It is a basic and "intuition request" question. I have asked it on StackExchange yet it is probably to specialized for it since there were no answears.

Generalised complex structure is defined to be a field of endomorphisms $\mathcal{J}$ of the big tangent bundle $T^{big}M=TM \oplus T^*M$ such that $\mathcal{J}^2=-I$ and **being orthogonal** with respect to "natural paring" - neutral metric - $<X+ \xi, Y+\eta>=\xi(Y)+\eta(X)$. The first condition gives reduction of structure group of $T^{big}M$ to complex group, **my question is why do we require the second condition?**

Comment: Are classical complex structures orthogonal with respect to some metric?

Comment: This is not a metric on the manifold. It is the natural pairing between tangent and cotangent bundles, induced by the interior product: it's natural to require orthogonality with respect to it. In a sense, I would say, it's just to keep tangent and cotangent bundles "equal but different".

Comment: @daniele I don't think anyone claimed it was a bonfide metric.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139305/the-space-of-generalized-complex-structures-in-sense-of-n-hitchin-is-contractibl

Answer (score 2):

This condition implies that $J $ preserves the natural pairing. This is quite typical; if one puts a metric on a complex manifold one usually requires the analogous condition to hold, making it a Kahler manifold.